# Opencv cuda python remap error cv.cuda.remap(raw, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I have installed opencv '4.2.0 dev' ,an already built package from https://jamesbowley.co.uk/accelerate-opencv-4-2-0-build-with-cuda-and-python-bindings/ (https://jamesbowley.co.uk/downloads/).I'm trying to use cv2.cuda.remap but it's throwing error as below

```
cv.cuda.remap(raw, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
```

my code

```
import numpy
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
npTmp = np.random.random((1024, 1024)).astype(np.float32)
npMat1 = np.stack([npTmp,npTmp],axis=2)
raw= cv.cuda_GpuMat()
raw.upload(npMat1)
a=np.array()
mapx = numpy.ndarray(shape=(640, 480, 1),
                           dtype='float32')
mapy = numpy.ndarray(shape=(640, 480, 1),
                           dtype='float32')

cv.cuda.remap(raw,a, mapx, mapy, cv.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
```

Comment: I haven't used the cuda version of this function, but my guess is that mapx and mapy should also be a gpuMat

Comment: After converting mapx and mapy to gpuMat I'm getting this error,

 a=cv.cuda.remap(raw,a, mapx_, mapy_, cv.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)

TypeError: an integer is required (got type cv2.cuda_GpuMat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Got the Answer!!!

Updated Code :

```
sz = (1024,1024,3)
npMat = (np.random.random(sz)*255).astype(np.uint8)
cuMat = cv.cuda_GpuMat(npMat)
npMapX = np.random.rand(sz[0],sz[1]).astype('float32')
npMapY = np.random.rand(sz[0],sz[1]).astype('float32')

cuMapX = cv.cuda_GpuMat(npMapX)
cuMapY = cv.cuda_GpuMat(npMapY)
```

you should then be able to remap with either

```
cuDst = cv.cuda_GpuMat(cuMat.size(),cuMat.type())
cv.cuda.remap(cuMat,cuMapX,cuMapY,dst=cuDst,interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)
```

or

```
cuDst = cv.cuda.remap(cuMat,cuMapX,cuMapY, interpolation=cv.INTER_LINEAR)
```